# How to I update the time in my access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to update the time into my database when I clicked on the button but I had error at the bolded part:

(startTime = dr[0].**ToString**();)

How do I resolve it?

```
    private void confirmbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        availabilitytabControl.SelectedTab = checkouttabPage;
        startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(checkintimelabel.Text);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = myAccessConnection();
        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand();

        try
        {
            myAccessConn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Time");
            DataTableCollection dta = myDataSet.Tables;
            DataColumnCollection drc = myDataSet.Tables["Time"].Columns;
            DataRowCollection dra = myDataSet.Tables["Time"].Rows;
            string startTime = null;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
            {
                *startTime = dr[0].**ToString**();*
            }

            string sqlStatement = "update Orders set Checkin_time=" +
                                   startTime + " where OrderNo='" + receiptNo + "'";
            myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, myAccessConn);
            myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
            myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
            "Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}",
            ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            myAccessConn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line? Your should use parameterized queries by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks. Maybe `dr[0]` is `null` and you will get ``NullReferenceExeption`?

Answer (score 0):

startTime is of type DateTime and you are trying to assign a string to it, why don't you do this :

```
 startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0].ToString());
```

Comment: Why would you convert a datetime value to string, and then convert back to a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You should never try passing DateTime values to database as a string (unless you know what you are doing exactly - should use ODBC Canonical format only then).

Second, as @soner already said, there is a much more serious problem in your code. You are not using parameters, thus open to SQL injection attack.

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime? startTime = ( DateTime.TryParse( checkintimelabel.Text, 
       CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
       DateTimeStyles.None,
       out dt )
  ? dt
  : (DateTime?)null;
// ...
```

Your foreach loop has no purpose, thus no need to correct that part but completely remove (neither that dataadapter has a purpose).

```
 string sqlStatement = @"update Orders 
                         set Checkin_time=@checkIn
                         where OrderNo=@orderNo";

var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, myAccessConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkIn", startTime);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderNo", receiptNo);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```